# Failed clean installation (WP and Cloudways)

Tags: wordpress, error, installation, mysql

I have read related topics but could not find any real help there, except that the same error message was issued on other occasions.

I'm trying to install 5.43.2 on WP on a cloudways brand new site. Local download works ok, except that I have to rename the locally downloaded folder "CiviCRM" (add "-wordpress-5.43.2.zip") to be able to upload to cloudways. Upload works fine. First install step is OK, only a warning about utf8mbXX which I need not bother about now, it says. I click Install and a serous warning message appears. Whereupon the WP access gets blocked with the following text:

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'srubjcrznr.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'srubjcrznr.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'srubjcrznr.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)
```

Unfortunately this goes beyond my faultfinding skills so I plead to you; is there anyone who can give a hand. The MySQL server is running. It seems as the first installation step does not create what is required!? This is a clean basic initial start, and it should just work I suppose. Tried it twice, did of course not help.  :-)

Claes

Comment: I'd expect to see that sort of error if you have a civicrm.settings.php file (perhaps from the first failed install attempt?) Do you have a file named that most likely in wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ or similar if it's there (then removing that and ensuring you don't have any tables with prefix "civicrm_" in the database) should get you to the state that the installer should run.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give It a try, but, in fact I erased the site after each try. And started a new site each time. One other problem that de CivCRM installation and set-up documentation often refers to CiviCRM 4.XX. Perhaps OK perhaps not.

Comment: I guess the other problem you could be seeing is that the install process ran part way so some of the database tables have been created and not others? Do you have any tables like 'civicrm_%' in the database you are trying to install into?

Comment: And what instructions are you trying to use?

Comment: I am having the same issue with a completely fresh WP install on Bluehost... tried several times and ways. I deleted all WP sites and deleted all databases between tries. the upload zip file is civicrm-5.49.1-wordpress.zip Any hints?